# How can I clear cache when I close my app?

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to clear the cache on my app when I exit?

I made webview app but it eat to much data and stored to cache. I wanted to clear it when I close the app.

I am using Java in Android studio

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the cache when the app is closed. For knowing when the app is closed from the recents list(destroyed), you can do this:

Add this code in your activity

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
   getCacheDir().delete();
}
```

This will clear the cache when the activity Is closed